# boost 1_49_0 error with gcc 3.3 mips32

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I am working on linux.
I am trying to pass from boost 1_45 to boost 1_49.
My code worked with boost 1_45 with both gcc.

I compile my code with multiple compiler.
With boost 1_49_0:
With gcc 4.4 it works. (It is for centos 6.4 x86_64)
With gcc 3.3 it doesn't compile. with 3.3 it is compiled for mips32 
I didn't find this error in google...

Code

```
 #include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
 ...
    boost::unordered_set< int >  po_refCombinedElements;
    po_refCombinedElementsp.insert(0);
```

Error

```
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp: In instantiation of `boost::unordered::detail::default_type_pointer<std::allocator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int> >, boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int>*>':
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp:358:   instantiated from `boost::unordered::detail::allocator_traits<std::allocator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int> > >'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/unique.hpp:107:   instantiated from `boost::unordered::detail::pick_node<std::allocator<int>, int>'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/unique.hpp:129:   instantiated from `boost::unordered::detail::set<std::allocator<int>, int, boost::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int> >'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/unordered_set.hpp:58:   instantiated from `boost::unordered::unordered_set<int, boost::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<int> >'
CrHealthAlarmContainer.cpp:43:   instantiated from here
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp:271: error:   invalid use of undefined type `struct          boost::unordered::detail::default_type_pointer<std::allocator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int> >, boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int>*>'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp:271: error: declaration of `struct   boost::unordered::detail::default_type_pointer<std::allocator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int> >, boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int>*>'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp:271: error: enumerator value for `value' not integer constant
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp: In instantiation of `boost::unordered::detail::default_type_const_pointer<std::allocator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int> >, const boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int>*>':
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp:365:   instantiated from `boost::unordered::detail::allocator_traits<std::allocator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int> > >'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/unique.hpp:107:   instantiated from `boost::unordered::detail::pick_node<std::allocator<int>, int>'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/unique.hpp:129:   instantiated from `boost::unordered::detail::set<std::allocator<int>, int, boost::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int> >'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/unordered_set.hpp:58:   instantiated from `boost::unordered::unordered_set<int, boost::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<int> >'
CrHealthAlarmContainer.cpp:43:   instantiated from here
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp:272: error: invalid use of undefined type `struct   boost::unordered::detail::default_type_const_pointer<std::allocator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int> >, const boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int>*>'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp:272: error: declaration of `struct   boost::unordered::detail::default_type_const_pointer<std::allocator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int> >, const boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int>*>'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp:272: error: enumerator  value for `value' not integer constant
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp: In instantiation of `boost::unordered::detail::default_type_difference_type<std::allocator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int> >, ptrdiff_t>':
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp:375:   instantiated from `boost::unordered::detail::allocator_traits<std::allocator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int> > >'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/unique.hpp:107:   instantiated from `boost::unordered::detail::pick_node<std::allocator<int>, int>'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/unique.hpp:129:   instantiated from `boost::unordered::detail::set<std::allocator<int>, int, boost::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int> >'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/unordered_set.hpp:58:   instantiated from `boost::unordered::unordered_set<int, boost::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<int> >'
CrHealthAlarmContainer.cpp:43:   instantiated from here
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp:275: error: invalid use of undefined type `struct  boost::unordered::detail::default_type_difference_type<std::allocator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int> >, ptrdiff_t>'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp:275: error: declaration of `struct boost::unordered::detail::default_type_difference_type<std::allocator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<int> >, ptrdiff_t>'
/rootdir/source/extlibs/boost/boost/unordered/detail/allocator_helpers.hpp:275: error: enumerator value for `value' not integer constant
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is why i got these error

Comment: Because GCC 3.3 was released in 2003?

Answer (score 0):

Boost [requires GCC 4.5 or higher](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation.html). I can't find a citation for Boost 1.49 but this'll still be the problem. I imagine they're using features that were buggy in your ancient GCC 3.3 (May 2003!)

Comment: @davidbobo: So, in that earlier Boost version, they didn't need those features...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit boost lists the minimum requirements as being [gcc-3.3](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html) however as with all non-primary targets, there is no guarantee that all the libraries and functionality will be available.

Comment: @davidbobo Just because Boost.config supports GCC-3.3 does not mean individual features will. You should either upgrade GCC or get a version in which the features you need support GCC-3.3

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I should have rephrased my comment. I linked where I got it in the release notes in my comment. However it makes it clear that they updated the minimum required version of GCC to 3.3 for Boost.Config... not Boost overall. Overall you are correct to compile ALL features of Boost, GCC-4.5 is required. Individual features may work with older versions on a case by case basis.